# Is 'interface' implemented in python just like in PHP

Tags: php, python, python-3.x

Is there any way to implement interface functionality in Python 3.x just like in PHP?
I would like to declare a method in parent class with no body but I would like to **force to override** this method in inherited classes.

(In PHP in case you don't override methods declared in interface then you get an error message)

In PHP way (below you get error message because you don't implement *getModel()* method):

```
interface Car { 
  public function setModel($name);
  public function getModel();
}

class miniCar implements Car {
  private $model; 

  public function setModel($name)
  { 
    $this -> model = $name; 
  }
}
```

Comment: [`NotImplementedError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#NotImplementedError) is related, but raised when calling a method instead of when defining the subclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into the `abc` module:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Car(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def setModel(self, name): 
        ...

    @abstractmethod
    def getModel(self):
        ...
```

Then, if you try to instantiate a class with no methods:

```
class MiniCar(Car):
    pass
x = MiniCar()
```

You get

> TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class MiniCar with abstract methods getModel, setModel